# If $a-b,\, a+b\in T$ for all $a, b\in T$ then $T=\{mx:x\in \mathbb{Z}\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

How to prove that if $T$ is a nonempty set of integer number so that $a-b,\, a+b\in T$ for all $a, b\in T$ then $T=\{mx:x\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ for some $m\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Hint: Use the well-ordering principle to conclude that there exists a smallest positive integer $m_{0}\in T$, then try to work your way up to a full proof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: First show that if $A$ has just one element, then $A=\{0\}$, and we can take $m=0$. Now assume that $A$ has at least two elements.

- Show that $A$ contains a positive integer.
- Let $m=\min\{a\in A:a>0\}$, and show that $A\supseteq\{mx:m\in\Bbb Z\}$.
- Finally, get a contradiction if there is an $n\in A\setminus\{mx:x\in\Bbb Z\}$ and conclude that $A=\{mx:m\in\Bbb Z\}$.